# Range piker in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where i use range piker from ant design.
The application has default values and should get new values when i click on `OK` after setting time.
The issue appear when i click on `OK`, because i get an Array like bellow:
[image]

But i should get just an array like :  
`onOk:
["2015-01-05T23:00:00.000Z", "2017-12-31T22:00:00.000Z"]`
 with both selected dates. How to solve this issue?

```js
function onChange(value, dateString) {
  console.log('Selected Time: ', value);
  console.log('Formatted Selected Time: ', dateString);
}

function onOk(value) {
  console.log('onOk: ', value);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <br />
 <RangePicker
        showTime={{ format: 'HH:mm' }}
        format="DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"
        onChange={onChange}
        onOk={onOk}
        defaultValue={[moment('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),moment('2018-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')]}
      />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
```

Comment: I can't find an `onOk` prop on the `RangePicker` component [documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker), but I think you should manage a state `value` that you pass to `RangePicker` as a prop value, and you should handle that logic in the `onChange` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the date in the format you have specified, we have to make use of ISO_8601 format. Just change the format prop of RangePicker to match ISO_8601 format.

```
 <RangePicker
      showTime={{ format: "HH:mm" }}
      defaultValue={[
        moment("2015/01/01", dateFormat),
        moment("2015/01/01", dateFormat)
      ]}
      onOk={onOk}
      format={moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ")}
    />
```

Here is a link for working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bxs6wc?file=index.js

Comment: Right now you pass the current day formatted to the format prop. Just pass `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` instead.